# Customize a "Feature"

Tags: 7, features, nodes

I'm trying to create a feature that includes an Automatic Nodetitle.

I want to change two things related to Automatic Nodetitle: Hide Title in content creation and populate the field with tokens.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [strongarm](http://drupal.org/project/strongarm) module. When creating the feature select "Strongarm" from the component section then look for the variables that start with ant_{content type name}

Automatic Nodetitle can have up to 3 different variables for every content type.

ant_'{content type name}
ant_pattern_'{content type name}
ant_php_'{content type name}

Export those variables out with your content type and you should be ok.

This works in Drupal 6 & 7.

Comment: Manual export of Strongarm variables == bummer! :)

Comment: Lol @ tim, I know I'm one of those guys that like to select my exports ;)

Comment: Marking this answer because it doesn't involve manually patching anything at this point and gets my feature working.

Answer (score 3):

Apply the patch I wrote, [#881170: Add Features support to Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/node/881170#comment-4490356), and it will work fine. When it works, comment on the issue and maybe the maintainer will eventually commit it.

Comment: That's for D6 tho?

Comment: There's a patch [here](http://drupal.org/node/881170#comment-4380720) for D7. I lost interest in writing a better patch for D7 because the maintainer is AWOL.

Comment: Yeah... seems to be some good stuff that's dead on the vine. I'll check that out.